# Parametrisation of Surfaces!!

Tags: integration, parametrization

An area A of $(x, y)$ plane bounded by $y$-axis and the parabola of the equation
$x=6-y^2$

Furthermore, a surface $F$ is given by the portion of the graph of the function $h (x, y) = 6-x-y^2$ which fulfils that $x\geq 0$ and $z\geq 0. $

1. Determine a parametrization for $A$ and $F$.

   Let $B$ denote the completed spatial regions related to those who are (vertically) between $A$ and $F$.
2. Determine a parametrization for $B$.

I am stuck on this problem for quite a while now. Any help with the parametrization will be really helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: I have tried to find the curve which I can rotate around the z-axis to form teh same shape. But I can not come up with a function that can do that and I have been stuck ever since.

Comment: 3D parametrization $ (x,y,z)=   [(6-u^2), u, v ] $ with $ ( u< \sqrt 6 , v>0 ) $

Comment: Hi @Narasimham , would that be for surface A or F?

Comment: A for (x,y); all three for F in 3D. A parabolic prismatic extruded cylinder.

Comment: Ah I see. I will try to work on it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by hand, so please verify these answers before trusting them. Notice that I maintained the same domains for all functions.

$A$ is defined by

$
\\x_A(t,u,v)=t
\\y_A(t,u,v)=u\sqrt{6-t}
\\z_A(t,u,v)=0
$
where 
$
\\0 \le t \le 6
\\-1 \le u \le 1
\\0 \le v \le 1
$

$F$ is defined by

$
\\x_F(t,u,v)=t
\\y_F(t,u,v)=u\sqrt{6-t}
\\z_F(t,u,v)=u^2(t-6)-t+6
$
where 
$
\\0 \le t \le 6
\\-1 \le u \le 1
\\0 \le v \le 1
$

And finally, $B$ is defined by

$
\\x_B(t,u,v)=t
\\y_B(t,u,v)=u\sqrt{6-t}
\\z_B(t,u,v)=v(u^2(t-6)-t+6)
$
where 
$
\\0 \le t \le 6
\\-1 \le u \le 1
\\0 \le v \le 1
$

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. I am new to MathJax.